asterisk register username mismatch
I'm having some issues with the registration of an extension configured in a Huawei HG8240H with the asterisk server.
The issue i'm facing is that the router is trying to register as username like username@domain and asterisk don't authenticate it
The asterisk version is 13.17.2, i know is an old one but we need chan_sip and we are trying to avoig pjsip for now because it is integrated in a system with the "old" config generator.
2024/11/25 11:31:24.203851 10.133.0.2:5070 -> 10.133.0.1:5060
REGISTER sip:example.com SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 10.133.0.2:5070;branch=z9hG4bKslppl010ki81pziij034s8kjn
Call-ID: 0l12n28z1c3ck48ipmz3c034pmz3c034@10.133.0.2
From: <sip:extn-1000@example.com>;tag=m4p3zp4p
To: <sip:extn-1000@example.com>
CSeq: 2 REGISTER
Contact: <sip:extn-1000@10.133.0.2:5070;transport=udp>
Supported: 100rel,replaces,timer,privacy,in-dialog
Expires: 600
Accept: application/sdp
Authorization: Digest username="extn-1000@example.com",realm="asterisk",nonce="0eea25cd",uri="sip:example.com",response="80a8aa08cb37b9cd98f07c2bfb585610",algorithm=MD5
Allow: INVITE,ACK,OPTIONS,BYE,CANCEL,REGISTER,INFO,PRACK,SUBSCRIBE,NOTIFY,UPDATE,MESSAGE,REFER
Max-Forwards: 70
User-Agent: HUAWEI-EchoLife HG8240H/V3R015C10S130
Session-ID: 6a386963313133316369333473386b6a
Content-Length: 0

and here is the asterisk log:
[2024-11-25T11:31:24.204385+0100] WARNING[4862]: chan_sip.c:17235 check_auth: username mismatch, have <extn-1000>, digest has <extn-1000@example.com>
[2024-11-25T11:31:24.204791+0100] NOTICE[4862]: chan_sip.c:28627 handle_request_register: Registration from '<sip:extn-1000@example.com>' failed for '10.133.0.2:5070' - Username/auth name mismatch

And my sip.conf file:
[general]
context=default
dtmfmode=auto
relaxdtmf=yes
port=5060
bindaddr=0.0.0.0
tcpenable=no
nat=force_rport,comedia
srvlookup=yes
allow=!all,alaw
allowguest=no
alwaysauthreject=yes
prefixlanguage=yes
accept_outofcall_message=no
useragent=Test PBX
send_diversion=yes
videosupport=no
notifyringing=yes
notifyhold=yes
allowsubscribe=no
callcounter=no
tonezone=es
directmedia=no

[extn-1000]
defaultuser=extn-1000
context=local
secret=uRikmQvkvqxqyGor
dtmfmode=rfc2833
callerid=1000 <1000>
mailbox=1000@local
host=dynamic
type=friend
directmedia=yes
language=es
qualify=1000
qualifyfreq=30
accountcode=1000
call-limit=2

Edit: If i set "secret=" (empty secret) for the extension, it registers correctly, but this way is insecure and i would like to avoid it.
